# GROUP_CONCAT as input of MySQL function

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use a GROUP_CONCAT in a SELECT as the input of a MySQL function? I cannot figure out how to cast the variable it seems. I've tried blob. I've tried text (then using another function to break it up into a result set, [here](http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/sql/mysql_stored_procedures.texy#String_functions)) but I haven't had any success.

I want to use it like this:

```
SELECT 
newCustomerCount(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT items.invoicenumber)) AS new_customers
FROM items;
```

Here is the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS newCustomerCount;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION newCustomerCount(invoicenumbers BLOB)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_customers INT;
    SET new_customers = 0;

    SELECT 
        SUM(nc.record) INTO new_customers
    FROM (
        SELECT
        1 AS customer,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person_to_invoice ps2 WHERE person_id = ps1.person_id AND invoice < ps1.invoice) AS previous_invoices
        FROM person_to_invoice ps1
        WHERE invoice IN(invoicenumbers)
        HAVING previous_invoices = 0
    ) nc;

    RETURN new_customers;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In your example query you are attempting to pass in all invoice numbers into your function to calculate the total number of new customers. Do you also need to support finding the number of new customers from just a subset of invoice numbers? If not, then it is not necessary to pass invoice numbers into your function.

Comment: Yes, it has to be from the subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Mysql functions do not support dynamic queries, I recommend you re-think your basic strategy to pass in a list of invoice numbers to your function. Instead, you could modify your function to accept a *single* invoice number and return the number of new customers just for the one invoice number.

Also, there are some optimizations you can make in your query for finding the number of new customers.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS newCustomerCount;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION newCustomerCount(p_invoice INT)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_customers INT;
    SET new_customers = 0;

    SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT ps1.person_id) INTO new_customers
    FROM 
      person_to_invoice ps1
    WHERE
      ps1.invoice = p_invoice
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM person_to_invoice ps2
      WHERE ps1.person_id = ps2.person_id
      AND ps2.invoice < ps1.invoice
    );

    RETURN new_customers;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can still get the total number of new customers for a given list of invoice numbers like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(newCustomerCount(invoice)) as total_new_customers
FROM items
WHERE ...
```

Comment: This is brilliant and works well - but there is one problem. I'm using an "items" table, which contains each item in an invoice. So because there are multiple rows with the same invoice number, it adds one new customer for each item, instead of one for each invoice. I'm going to work on this issue and see what I can do. Thanks for this, its a great start and would work in 99% of the cases. I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could try FIND_IN_SET() instead of IN(). The performance will probably be horrible when passing in a long list of invoice numbers. But it should work.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(invoice, invoicenumbers)
```

Comment: This is indeed true, but in my table is is excruciatingly slow and, as I've read, can't be optimized and won't use indexes. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place.

`WHERE invoice IN(invoicenumbers)` will not do the desired substitution.  Instead you need to use `CONCAT` to construct the SQL, then `prepare` and `execute` it.

Comment: Good idea, but I tried and discovered this: Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger. I can't make it a procedure, because i need to call it as part of a select statement.